# selecting current and previous value from consecutive rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a result set from where I need to extract an output. The result set as follows:

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| Issue_id | create_date | transtimestamp | Npriority |
+----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| 556365   | 2020-02-02  | 1580628330     | 2         |
| 556365   | 2020-02-02  | 1580629317     | 0         |
| 773656   | 2020-02-02  | 1580608104     | 1         |
| 773656   | 2020-02-02  | 1580609625     | 0         |
| 111252   | 2020-02-02  | 1580622323     | 1         |
| 111252   | 2020-02-02  | 1580623399     | 2         |
+----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
```

I would like to generate an output from the above:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Issue_id | create_date | prev_value | cur_value |
+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| 556365   | 2020-02-02  | 2          | 0         |
| 773656   | 2020-02-02  | 1          | 0         |
| 111252   | 2020-02-02  | 1          | 2         |
+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

I am using something as follows but not able to get the desired result set:

```
select  Issue_id,Npriority,lag(Npriority)   over (partition by Issue_id order by trantimestamp) as prev_value FROM (select * from results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.

```
with data as (
  select 
  *
  , lag(Npriority,1) over (partition by Issue_id order by transtimestamp asc) as prev_Npriority -- Get previous
  , row_number() over (partition by Issue_id order by transtimestamp desc) as rn -- order by most recent
 from `project.dataset.table`
)
select Issue_id, create_date, prev_Npriority as prev_value, Npriority as cur_value
from data 
where rn = 1 -- filter to most recent
```

Comment: Thank you rtenha. Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery can do this with aggregation:

```
select Issue_id, create_date,
       array_agg(Npriority order by transtimestamp desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)] as latest_value,
       array_agg(Npriority order by transtimestamp desc limit 2)[ordinal(2)] as prev_value
from results r
group by Issue_id create_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple self join

```
select a.Issue_id, a.create_date, b.cur_value as prev_value, a.cur_value
from results a inner join results b on a.Issue_id = b.Issue_id 
and a.transtimestamp   > b.transtimestamp
```

Comment: Thank you zip. Thanks for the quick response. Really useful